# Get the value of an object from the value of another key

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, typescript

I have a Typescript project in which I have two objects. What I am doing is getting a data from the second object depending on the value of the first object.

This is the first object:

```
let sheet = [
  {
      desc: "work"
  },
  {
      desc: "serv"
  }
]
```

This is the second object:

```
let list = [
  {
    "properties": {
      "sheetId": 1000297558,
      "title": "work",
      "index": 0
    }
  },
  {
    "properties": {
      "sheetId": 24134863,
      "title": "serv",
      "index": 1
  }
]
```

What I want: Get the value of the `sheetId` property where the value of the `title` property of that object is equal to the value of the `desc` property of the first object

This is what I do:

```
let sheetId: number

for (let getSheet of sheet ) {
  for (let getList of list) {
    if (getList.properties.title == getSheet.desc) {
      sheetId = getList.properties.sheetId
      .
      .
      .
    }
  }
}
```

**My problem**: I am iterating twice, each one on an object, this when the process is large consumes a lot, I would like to know if there is another more efficient way to do this

Comment: i dont understand what you  are trying to do in the for loop. you are overwriting `sheetId` and you will get last element that is going inside the `if`

Comment: @cmgchess What I want is to obtain the sheetId of the object where the title is equal to the value of desc, to then operate with it, this is just an example to get the id then inside the for I have operations with that id. The problem is that when it is very big the object takes a long time, so I wanted to know if there is a faster or better way to do it

Comment: @stark I added an answer. Did you get a chance to look into that. Hope it will work as per your expectation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert the `list` to a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) of `sheetId` by `title` O(n) (where `n` is the length of `list`), and then extract the `sheetId` from the Map in O(1).

Basically a Map is an object the hold `[key, value]` pairs. You can get the value by calling the `.get()` method with the key. In your case, to prevent iterating the `list` multiple type, we can iterate it once to index the `sheetId` by `title`.

```js
const sheet = [{"desc":"work"},{"desc":"serv"}]

const list = [{"properties":{"sheetId":1000297558,"title":"work","index":0}},{"properties":{"sheetId":24134863,"title":"serv","index":1}}]

const sheetIdByTitle = new Map(list.map(({ properties: p }) => [p.title, p.sheetId]))

console.log(sheetIdByTitle.get(sheet[0].desc))

const ids = sheet.map(o => sheetIdByTitle.get(o.desc))

console.log(ids)
```

Comment: I see that it works but I don't understand what the map does with those two values, could you explain this process to me a little so I can understand it well before using it?

Comment: I've added a link to the Map's description in mdn.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand it correctly, You have both the arrays with same length and in same order. If Yes, you can try this solution.

```js
let sheet = [{
  desc: "work"
}, {
  desc: "serv"
}];

let list = [{
  "properties": {
    "sheetId": 1000297558,
    "title": "work",
    "index": 0
  }
}, {
  "properties": {
    "sheetId": 24134863,
    "title": "serv",
    "index": 1
  }
}];

const res = list.map((obj, index) => obj.properties.title === sheet[index].desc ? obj.properties.sheetId : 'Not matched!');

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this variation as well.

```
let descToSheetIdMap = list.reduce((p, c) => {
  p[c.properties.title] = c.properties.sheetId
  return p
}, {});

for (let getSheet of sheet ) {
  sheetId = descToSheetIdMap[getSheet.desc];
  .
  .
  .
}
```